# Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50000010 }

Tags: android

I got the ANR from Google Report,
I don't know what's going on and how to solve this problem.
Anyone know what's happened?

**Occur add Android 7.0 7.1**

error log:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x75202000 self=0x7f85e96a00
  | sysTid=10438 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f8a3f3a98
  | state=S schedstat=( 34499430902 5874352557 56073 ) utm=2681 stm=768 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fca788000-0x7fca78a000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 00000000000786e8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 0000000000020378  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+140)
  #02  pc 0000000000055a80  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+256)
  #03  pc 0000000000056a24  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState15waitForResponseEPNS_6ParcelEPi+708)
  #04  pc 000000000004b4cc  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder8transactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j+72)
  #05  pc 00000000001007cc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  #06  pc 000000000088b078  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+196)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (BinderProxy.java)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:615)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query (ContentProviderProxy.java:419)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:534)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:475)
```

my code

```
Cursor cursor = 
resolver.query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), 
new String[] {BaseColumns._ID}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = ?",
new String[] {path}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " desc");
```

Comment: You are showing some code in your question. From the ANR, how do you know which part of the code is causing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANR errors - SCREEN OFF - How am I supposed to handle them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082321/anr-errors-screen-off-how-am-i-supposed-to-handle-them)

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I am facing the same issue